# Silverstripe image moving from one folder to another freezes screen and no operations can be performed after that

Tags: silverstripe

I am using Silverstripe 3.0 and everything is running fine. Suddenly I faced an issue while moving images from one folder to another from admin/assets section.

In this section when we click on the folder it takes us inside the folder and shows all the images inside that in grid view. When we click on any image then it takes us to the image details page (for example admin/assets/EditForm/field/File/item/1917/edit) where we have the details of the image such as File name, Title, Owner and a drop down Folder which shows the folder in which the image is located.

When I change the folder from the drop down and want to move the image to selected folder, then during the process the screen freezes and none of the actions happen though in console all the ajax calls can be seen working and no error in console. Once I refresh the page then all the things work normal and the image which I moved to other folder is there in other folder.

Any help or Idea where I can look for the issue ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite explanatory but it is not possible to give a perfect solution to your answer. As a guess I can say that you have some issue with redirection in your code in framework/forms/gridfield/GridFieldDetailForm.php page.

As you said you are using 3.0 so I have tested this issue in 3.15 and found that there is no such issue. I would suggest you to replace the old file with this new one in Silverstripe 3.15 and see if that works. If it does work than you can compare these two files and pin point the cause of the issue.

But always remember to take a backup first and then do such thing.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.... You are the Boss... Cheers.. I will compare these two files and try to figure out the exact issue.